# How to catch and handle "the server was not found or was not accessible"

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using the code below. When the SQL Server is off I get an error

> the server was not found or was not accessible

when I'm in debug mode in VS2013 (as expected). If I launch the program outside of the IDE it just crashes.

How can I catch and handle the situation if the SQL Server can't be contacted?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    CmdString = "SELECT * FROM Conversions WHERE Completed = 'False'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Conversions");

    sda.Fill(dt);  // this is where the exception happens
}
```

Comment: have you put any try catch blocks in?

Comment: put a try ..catch around the block of code and handle `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` for such type of exceptions.

Comment: This is why you use `Try` / `Catch` blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked, thanks guys!

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                CmdString = "SELECT * FROM Conversions WHERE Completed = 'False'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, con);
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("Conversions");


                try
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (SqlException sqlexc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error:  " + sqlexc.Message);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error:  " + exc.Message);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Number` property of `SqlException` for more options.

Comment: You could put the try{} up higher, above the CmdString variable, so that all errors are caught.